# Keep sliding when click to other page

Tags: jquery, slider

I've made a full background slider, but when I click on a menu-item the slider starts over and over. Is it possible that if I click on a menu-item (to another page) that the slider keeps sliding?

Here is my code of the slider:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow img.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow img:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow img:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1500, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 10000);
});


<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">RM</a>
        </li>

        <div class="diagonal"></div>

        <li>
            <a href="">Offerte</a>
        </li>

        <div class="diagonal"></div>

        <li>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div id="slideshow">
   <img src="img/Route 163.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 1" class="active">
   <img src="img/Spring.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 2">
   <img src="img/Road to America.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 3">
   <img src="img/Kopenhagen.jpg" alt="Slideshow Image 4">
</div>
```

Comment: Where are the menu links in this code

Comment: Does link will open a new page having same slider ?

Comment: Slider will restart as page will be refreshed, slider can not continue from the last position in this case.

Comment: And is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you give me an example of that?